# PercentileIF Excel (or rangeif)

Tags: excel, vba, percentile

A B
1 5
2 10
2 15
3 20

I want to calculate percentile for a column of values B if A is equal say 2. That's I want to get range of B2,B3 and calculate percentile of this.

So basically the question is: how do I select range in one column with the checking with another column?

I.e. it works perfectly with SumIf and CountIf, I just need the same with PercentileIf. Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you the 25th percentile of A1:A6 for all cells where the value in B1:B6 equals 2:

```
=PERCENTILE.INC(IF(B1:B6=2,A1:A6,""),0.25)
```

It's an [array formula](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/array.htm) and must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>.